# Default the Opportunity screen after Lead conversion

Tags: apex, visualforce, controller, opportunity, lead-conversion

<strike>I have a custom vf page which is controlling the conversion process from Lead to Account. What I'd like to achieve is that once I convert the system automatically redirects to the opportunity page. Could you please advise how this can be achieved?</strike>

How from the standard conversion page `/lead/leadconvert.jsp?id=someID&nooppti=0&nooverride=1&retURL=%2FsomeOtherID` I can redirect to Opportunity when pressing the "Convert" button?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a solution in https://success.salesforce.com/answers?id=9063A000000l4LlQAI

Thanks for your help anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You can redirect to opportunity page using PageReference

Refer [PageReference class in apex](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_system_pagereference.htm)

Comment: How from the standard conversion page /lead/leadconvert.jsp?id=someID&nooppti=0&nooverride=1&retURL=%2FsomeOtherID I can redirect to Opportunity when pressing the "Convert" button?